# Django: How do I delete Inlines dynamically?

Tags: django, inline

Django: How do I delete Inlines dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason users with no permission to the object still have access to it through Inlines. Here's how to delete them dynamically:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ['SomeInline']
    ...
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        def delete_inlines(inlines):
            for index, inline in reversed(list(enumerate(self.inlines))):
                if inline.__name__ in inlines:
                   del self.inlines[index]
                   del self.inline_instances[index]
        delete_inlines(['SomeInline' ])
        return super(FooAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=None)
```